# Could not find driver pdo_pgsql symfony 2.8

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony

I made a lot of search and didn't find any solution.
Whenever I try to php app/console doctrine:database:create, SF2 returns me an error "could not find driver".

I went in /app/config.php and configured my php.ini correctly.
Extensions are uncommented and enabled.

php -m tells me pgsql is activated.
phpinfo(); too, and also tells me the path of the bin which's used. (which is the one noticed on /web/config.php).

I tried all I could, but i can't create a database.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   pdo_pgsql
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8


extension=pgsql.so
extension=pdo_pgsql.so (in php.ini)
```

I don't know ...

Comment: Running on windows or Linux ?

Comment: Can you show your parameters.yml file?

Comment: MacOS with MAMP. Moved my symfony project into mamp's apache server.

Comment: parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 5432
    database_name: need4truck
    database_user: julien
    database_password: root
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: 881ee9ad40c61baf752b41187bbe4482996f1497

Comment: can you check whether pdo_pgsql is loaded or not using `phpinfo()` ?

Comment: pgsql

PostgreSQL Support enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version 8.4.17

Comment: pdo_pgsql

PDO Driver for PostgreSQL enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version 8.4.17
Module version 7.0.0

Comment: It's possible that you have two different php.ini files, one for console and one for the web server.  php --ini will tell you which ini file is being used by the console. php --re pdo_pgsql should verify that pdo_pgsql (not just pgsql) is loaded.

Comment: php --ini tells me /etc/php.ini is used, and php --re pdo_pgsql tells me "pdo_pgsql does not existe"

Comment: And you are sure that /etc/php.ini has extension=pdo_pgsql.so uncommented out?

Comment: Actually there is no extension=pdo_pgsql commented, juste windows .dll because symfony2 appears to use my native's OS PHP which is 5.5.30 and I'd really enjoy him to use the one of my web's server. Furthermore, i downloaded a new package to upgrade php, (currently using php 7 :) when I try a php -v in console) but Symfony STILL use the old one 5.5.30 which has no extension in it .......... How can I tell to symfony to use my web's server PHP or my upgrated local based PHP ? Thanks fo your responses

Comment: It's a question of adjusting your PATH variable to point to the correct php executable.  It's not a Symfony issue but rather an operating system one.

Answer (score 1):

Install Postgresql:

```
apt-get install postgresql postgresql-client
apt-get install php7.0-pgsql // or 5.5.9 your version
```

In /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini, add or check: (this is in fact optional)

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, my SF2 project was using a wrong php bin (wrong path).
My web server's correctly running with php 7 but my CLI's using php 5 bin. Simply create a script in your ~/.bashrc_profile (mac user) and copy/paste this into it : `

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

(if you installed php 7 on your mac and his bin is located in /usr/local/php5).

If you're using MAMP as webserver, copy paste this :

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/bin:$PATH
```

Then you can tip

```
php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

And enjoy !

Answer (score 0):

On Windows I just had to install postgresql and issue was resolved